# Two Definitions for $E(X)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Given that $\int_{\Omega}|X(\omega)|dP(\omega)<\infty$ and $\mu_X$ to be the induced probability measure of $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n $. Why is it that

\begin{equation*}
\int_\Omega X(\omega)dP(\omega)
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}xd \mu_X(x)
\end{equation*}

are equivalent definition for the expected value of $X$, $E(X)$?

This might seem trivial to some. But none is trivial to a beginner. Can someone elaborate please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is called the 'change of variables' formula. To prove this, first show that $$\int_{\Omega}f(X(\omega))\,P(\mathrm{d}\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\,\mu_X(\mathrm{d}x)$$ holds for $f(x)=\mathbf{1}_{B}(x)$ where $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then show, by suitable convergence theorem, that this continues to hold any non-negative measurable functions $f$ (and hence $\mu_X$-integrable functions as well).

Comment: Thanks @SangchulLee! I guess this is just the same with what we've discussed recently with @KaviRamaMurthy. Inquiry for notations, is $P(d \omega)=dP(\omega)$ and $\mu_X (dx)=d\mu_X(x)$? Or they differ in any sense?

Comment: That is true, I see that my comment is the same as in the answer below. Also, there is no difference in those notations as you speculated. The former seems more prevalent in probability-theory context, while the letter dominant in analysis context.

Comment: Okay :) Thanks again @SangchulLee

Answer (score 3):

$\mu_X$ is defined by $\mu_X(A)=P(X^{-1}(A))$. This can be written as $\int I_A d\mu_X=\int I_A(X) dP$. [ Because $I_A(X(\omega)) =I_{X^{-1}(A)}(\omega)$]. For any simple function $f$ we get $\int fd\mu_X=\int f(X) dP$. From here you can use a standard measure theoretic argument to say that the equation hods for any non-negative measurable function $f$ as also for any $f$ which is integrable w.r.t. $\mu_X$. Taking $f(x)=x$ you get the equation you want provided the integral exists (which is true iff $X$ has finite mean).

Comment: @Crunchy Don't hesitate to ask for more details, if need be.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness, Professor. I'm struggling to understand the second sentence. Could you please elaborate more. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @Crunchy In the second sentence I am using  the fact that any simple function is of the form $f=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k I_{A_k}$. So you get this step by taking linear combinations in the previous step.

Comment: I mean, i'm struggling in the line $\int I_A d\mu_X=\int  I_A (X)dP$. Can this be proven easily? I have no clue though how to use the "because". Sorry.. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: By definition $\int I_Ad\mu =\mu (A)$. Similarly, $\int_{X^{-1}(A)} dP=P(X^{-1}(A))$.

Comment: Ahh... I get it professor. :) So your using the fact that $\int_{X^{-1}A}dP=\int I_{x^{-1}}(A)dP$. I also understand the 3rd sentence. So what do you mean about "standard measure theoretic argument"? Do you mean about the way Lebesgue integral is define via simple functions then nonnegative? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Exactly. It looks like you are getting  the entire proof now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @KaviRamaMurthy .

Answer (score 0):

I would think of this in the binary case.  Say we have only two sets, $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$.  Say $X(\omega_0) = 10$ and $X(\omega_1)=20$.  Let $P(\omega_0)=.2$ and $P(\omega_1)=.8$.  Now compute the expectation of $X(\omega)$ where we consider $\omega$ to be a random event, i.e. $\int X(\omega)dP(\omega)$.  The induced measure on the set 10, 20, puts the identical weights of .2 and .8 on these values and therefore the expectation, $\int x d\mu(x)$ is the same.

Comment: Sorry, i don't really get what you mean about "binary case" and $\omega$'s are not sets. @JonathanLevy

Comment: I'm sorry.  What I mean is the case of having only two sets in the sample space $\Omega$.  I was saying it is binary because you either draw $\omega_0$ or not. It does not matter if $\omega$'s are sets or not.  Treat them as events.

Comment: I get what you mean. But it's just a very particular example. Thanks though! :) @JonathanLevy

Comment: It was meant as just an easy heuristic to see why it holds, lest expectation lose its natural meaning, but don’t count out the simplest cases as this is extendable to any discrete case.  For a practical stats person, that pretty much does it!